# JPA OneToMany - iteration over cascade objects and garbage collector

Tags: java, jpa, garbage-collection, one-to-many

I have a classic DB structure with **Quiz**, a collection of **Questions** for each quiz, and a collection of **Answers** for each question, and associated Entity classes.

Assume, the quiz has a hundred questions, and each question has a hundred answers, and I need to iterate over each question and then iterate over each answer, and then do some time-consuming logic on each answer. So the execution of the whole loop takes significant time.

If I iterate in this way:

```java
for (Question q: quiz.getQuestions()) // triggers lazy loading of all questions of the quiz
{
    for(Answer a: q.getAnswers()) // triggers lazy loading of all answers of the question
    {
        longReadOnlyProcessingOfAnswer(a);
    }
}
```

After each iterating answers, I don't need them anymore, but they are still in memory, and GC is not going to thrash them.
By the end of this long execution, the quiz with all the questions and all the answers will consume a lot of memory (tens of megabytes)

Is there a way to get rid of unnecessary objects in memory by keeping this lazyLoading approach?
Or I should switch to getting answers from the database directly?

Comment: Well, if we assume that `a` and `q` are lists, you could remove the entities from the list after you're done with them, which would presumably make them eligible for gc. However, the lazy loading might very well complicate things here since there are usually proxy classes created. I try to remove the lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

Just 'pop' the questions one by one from `quiz.getQuestions()`. Once you're done with processing the answers to a particular question, do an `EntityManager.flush()` to synchronize changes, and then `EntityManager.detach(question)` to remove the `question` from the persistence context. Make sure you have `cascade = DETACH` on top of `Question.answers`. This should make the processed `Question`s, together with their `Answer`s eligible for GC.

(I am assuming `Quiz.questions` is not the owning side of the association between the two entities)

You could also try fetching `Question`s in batches using a query, processing them, flushing, and then clearing the `EntityManager` after every batch. This will allow you to easily fine-tune the batch size for optimal performance.